# Implement a function which takes a string as an input and returns a new one without consonant letters replaced with "!"

Tags: c++

UPD: 
I rewrote the function, added an extra array in which to write new variables. But alas, the function is not working right now, and the text is not clear. And I don't understand what's wrong
My code:

```
bool IsConsonant(char ch)
{
    const char* consonant = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";
    for (size_t c = 0; consonant[c] != '\0'; ++c)
        if (ch == consonant[c])
            return true;
    return false;
}

char* ReplaceConsonant(char* str)
{
    size_t size = strlen(str);
    char* ch = new char[size + 1];
    for (size_t index = 0; str[index] != '\0'; ++index)
    {
        str[index] = ch[index];
        if (IsConsonant(ch[index]))
            ch[index] = '!';
    }
    return ch;
    delete[] ch;
}


int main()
{
    const char* ch = "I like this";
    const char* rez = ReplacedConsonant(ch);
    std::cout << rez;
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use string?

Comment: Give more details about the error.

Comment: First thing to do: Please [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your code. Your code as it stands here is unreadable and therefore it's very hard to spot errors, even for us.

Comment: You try to modify constant string...

Comment: @Vova Makarovych The program has undefined bahvior. You may not change string literals. Moreover the type of the argument does not correspond to the type of the function parameter.

Comment: You are trying to pass a `const char*` (a non-modifiable string) to a function that wants a `char*` (a modifiable string). That cannot work.

Comment: You're passing a `const char *` to a `char *`. That is potentially problematic at best.

Comment: @Chipster sorry, I misread that, my bad. Thanks. I'll delete the comment. You can delete your's too.

Comment: This kind of problem requires that you extract a [mcve] first. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const char *ch;` declares an immutable c-style-string. You can not pass that to a function that takes `char*` (a modifiable string) as a paramter. Since this question is tagged with c++, I recommend you use `std::string` and some other c++ functions to make your life easier.

```
std::string ReplacedConsonant(std::string str)
{
    std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), IsConsonant, '!');

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string ch = "I like this";
    std::string res = ReplacedConsonant(ch);

    std::cout << res;
}
```

This also satisfies the title of your question that this function returns a new string instead of modifying the existing one.

Comment: how can i replace my isconsonant lambda function?

Comment: What do you mean with "replace" and why? Also thats not a lamba.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, type of argument str of ReplacedConsonant(char* str) is char*, which is pointer to char, and you tried to pass variable ch as argument, and ch is of type 
const char* which is pointer to const char. So you are basically trying to convert const to non const var, which is compile time error.
Anyway, changing string literal is undefined behaviour, because string literals are, most probably placed in read-only part of memory, and modifiing read-only part is nonsense, I think.

This should work

```
int main() {
    char ch[] = "I like this";
    const char* rez = ReplacedConsonant(ch);
    std::cout << rez;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looked UPD.  I rewrote the function

Answer (score 1):

You currently try to modify constant string, change your calling code to:

```
int main()
{
    char ch[] = "I like this";
    const char* rez = ReplacedConsonant(ch);
    std::cout << rez;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the function parameter (without the qualifier `const`)

```
char* ReplacedConsonant(char* str);
```

means that the string passed to the function will be changed.

So you may not pass to the function a constant string.

Thus in main declare a non constant array instead of the pointer to a string literal. For example

```
int main()
{
    char ch[] = "I like this";
    std::cout << ReplacedConsonant(ch) << '\n';
}
```

Also in general it is better to declare the function the following way

```
char * ReplacedConsonant( char *str, char c = '!' );
```

In this case you can substitite consonant letters to any character. Within the function body write

```
if ( IsConsonant( str[index] ) ) str[index] = c;
```